# Find values in a given interval without a vector scan

Tags: r, data.table, intervals

With a the R package `data.table` is it possible to find the values that are in a given interval without a full vector scan of the data. For example

```
>DT<-data.table(x=c(1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89))
>my.data.table.function(DT,min=3,max=10)
   x
1: 3
2: 5
3: 8
```

Where `DT` can be a very big table.

Bonus question: 
is it possible to do the same thing for a set of non-overlapping intervals such as

```
>I<-data.table(i=c(1,2),min=c(3,20),max=c(10,40))
>I
   i min max
1: 1   3  10
2: 2  20  40
> my.data.table.function2(DT,I)
   i  x
1: 1  3
2: 1  5
3: 1  8
4: 2 21
5: 2 34
```

Where both `I` and `DT` can be very big. 
Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you limiting yourself to integer valued keys?

Comment: No, any type that can be ordered is in the scope of my question. Why?

Comment: Floating points are more problematic, that's all.

Comment: Sorry, I am not clear about that. I would say that the code proposed by @user1935457 works also for floats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `vecseq` isn't exported as a visible function from `data.table`, so its syntax and/or behavior here could change without warning in future updates to the package.  Also, this is *untested* besides the simple `identical` check at the end.

That out of the way, we need a bigger example to exhibit difference from vector scan approach:

```
require(data.table)

n <- 1e5L
f <- 10L
ni <- n / f

set.seed(54321)
DT <- data.table(x = 1:n + sample(-f:f, n, replace = TRUE))
IT <- data.table(i = 1:ni, 
                 min = seq(from = 1L, to = n, by = f) + sample(0:4, ni, replace = TRUE),
                 max = seq(from = 1L, to = n, by = f) + sample(5:9, ni, replace = TRUE))
```

`DT`, the Data Table is a not-*too*-random subset of `1:n`.  `IT`, the Interval Table is `ni = n / 10` non-overlapping intervals in `1:n`.  Doing the repeated vector scan on all `ni` intervals takes a while:

```
system.time({
  ans.vecscan <- IT[, DT[x >= min & x <= max], by = i]
})
 ##  user  system elapsed 
 ## 84.15    4.48   88.78
```

One can do two rolling joins on the interval endpoints (see the `roll` argument in `?data.table`) to get everything in one swoop:

```
system.time({
  # Save time if DT is already keyed correctly
  if(!identical(key(DT), "x")) setkey(DT, x)

  DT[, row := .I]

  setkey(IT, min)

  target.low <- IT[DT, roll = Inf, nomatch = 0][, list(min = row[1]), keyby = i]

  # Non-overlapping intervals => (sorted by min => sorted by max)
  setattr(IT, "sorted", "max")

  target.high <- IT[DT, roll = -Inf, nomatch = 0][, list(max = last(row)), keyby = i]

  target <- target.low[target.high, nomatch = 0]
  target[, len := max - min + 1L]


  rm(target.low, target.high)

  ans.roll <- DT[data.table:::vecseq(target$min, target$len, NULL)][, i := unlist(mapply(rep, x = target$i, times = target$len, SIMPLIFY=FALSE))]
  ans.roll[, row := NULL]
  setcolorder(ans.roll, c("i", "x"))
})
 ## user  system elapsed 
 ## 0.12    0.00    0.12
```

Ensuring the same row order verifies the result:

```
setkey(ans.vecscan, i, x)
setkey(ans.roll, i, x)
identical(ans.vecscan, ans.roll)
## [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I just have one little concern: The line `target.low <- IT[DT, roll = Inf, nomatch = 0]` creates a structure with the same number of row as DT. Therefore the complexity of the computation is `n*log(i)` where `i=nrow(IT)` and `n=nrow(DT)`. Yet we can easily transform this code into a `i*log(n)` complexity which is an advantage as most of time n>>i. I post the code in a separate answer. I anyway mark your answer as accepted  as you provided all the key ideas.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a variation of the code proposed by @user1935457 (see comment in @user1935457 post)

```
system.time({

 if(!identical(key(DT), "x")) setkey(DT, x)
 setkey(IT, min)

 #below is the line that differs from @user1935457 
 #Using IT to address the lines of DT creates a smaller intermediate table
 #We can also directly use .I 
 target.low<-DT[IT,list(i=i,min=.I),roll=-Inf, nomatch = 0][,list(min=min[1]),keyby=i]
 setattr(IT, "sorted", "max")

 # same here
 target.high<-DT[IT,list(i=i,max=.I),roll=Inf, nomatch = 0][,list(max=last(max)),keyby=i]
 target <- target.low[target.high, nomatch = 0]
 target[, len := max - min + 1L]

 rm(target.low, target.high)
 ans.roll2 <- DT[data.table:::vecseq(target$min, target$len, NULL)][, i := unlist(mapply(rep, x = target$i, times = target$len, SIMPLIFY=FALSE))]
 setcolorder(ans.roll2, c("i", "x"))
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#    0.07    0.00    0.06 


system.time({ 
 # @user1935457 code
 })
#    user  system elapsed 
#    0.08    0.00    0.08 

identical(ans.roll2, ans.roll)
#[1] TRUE
```

The performance gain is not huge here, but it shall be more sensitive with larger `DT` and smaller `IT`.  thanks again to @user1935457 for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do a full vector scan, you should first declare your variable as a key for your `data.table` :

```
DT <- data.table(x=c(1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89),key="x")
```

Then you can use `%between%` :

```
R> DT[x %between% c(3,10),]
   x
1: 3
2: 5
3: 8

R> DT[x %between% c(3,10) | x %between% c(20,40),]
    x
1:  3
2:  5
3:  8
4: 21
5: 34
```

**EDIT :** As @mnel pointed out, `%between%` still does vector scans. The Note section of the help page says :

> Current implementation does not make use of ordered keys.

So this doesn't answer your question.

Comment: These are still vector scans!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I just have the feeling that using ordered key + rolling joins it should be easy to locate the upper and lower bounds of the interval, and then get all the values in between . Yet I did not notice the `between` function in the `data.table` package. If this function do vector scan this maybe means that the feature I look for is not implemented yet.