# Fast data.table filtering

Tags: r, data.table, subset

I've a use case where I want to rapidly filter data tables repeatedly. I've a feeling that if I use a simple filter like `df[val>0,]` the scan is `O(N)`, but if I simply set the `val` field as a key then I should be able to filter faster, but not sure how. As an example I've done the following

a sorted data.table

```
df_sort = data.table(id = seq(1, 100000), val = runif(100000, 0, 1))
setkeyv(df_sort, c('val')
```

a regular data.table

```
df = data.table(id = seq(1, 100000), val = runif(100000, 0, 1))
```

The case I want to do is find unique `id`'s for `val > tol`. Using `rbenchmark` I did the following

```
benchmark('raw' = { l = length(unique(df$id[df$val >=0.1]))}, 'sort' = {l = length(unique(df_sort$id[df_sort$val >=0.1]))}, replications=20)
```

the result I got showed no difference between the two.

```
  test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
1  raw           20   0.440    1.005     0.494        0          0         0
2 sort           20   0.438    1.000     0.540        0          0         0
```

Could someone give some pointers on how to accomplish this? Is it even possible?

**EDIT**

Tried out a suggestion in the comment, came back worse. Not sure why.

```
benchmark('raw' = { l = df[val >=0.1, uniqueN(id)]}, 'sort' = {l = df_sort[val >=0.1, uniqueN(id)]}, replications=200)

test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
1  raw          200   0.770    1.000     0.928        0          0         0
2 sort          200   1.361    1.768     1.691        0          0         0
```

Comment: don't forget to use `set.seed` to compare random data.

Comment: If you actually use data.table syntax (which you don't do here) a lot of internal optimizations happen (including sorting). Try something like d[val>=0.1, uniqueN(id)].

Comment: You should study the data.table vignettes. A lot of work has gone into them and they are quite excellent. You don't have to rely on your feelings if you read documentation.

Comment: Turns out the `length(unique(...))` is faster than `uniqueN`

Comment: That definitely shouldn't be the case. Can't test right now. Maybe I'll have a look tomorrow. Also, you really should set seeds or use copy to create identical data.tables.

Comment: Can you put everything into one benchmark please?

Comment: Re `uniqueN` - This is a [known issue](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1120). It had some improvements in [the recent versions though](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md#new-features). Regarding your filtering comparison, data.table sets a secondary key after you run your filtering once, so it should be as fast as running on a keyed data.table. Also, I'm not sure what is the issue you are having. Does it run slow? Or you are just being curious? Lastly, `df$id[df$val >=0.1]` has nothing to do with data.tble. It's just a vector subset.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I'm trying to see if there is a fast way to get to a subset of a column based on values in another column provided that other column is sorted. The simplest way would be to scan row by row, but if the `val` column is sorted, a `val >=0.1` should (in principle)  jump straight to that cut point (because its sorted) and proceed from there on. So I'm expecting to see a speed up, but don't.

Comment: In both of your cases the key isn't used. When doing `df$id[df$val >=0.1]` you are just doing base R full vector scan (`df$id` is just a vector, hence it isn't aware of any keys), hence there shouldn't be any difference in your first benchmark. Regarding your second attempt, it looks like keys weren't implemented yet for `<=`. You will see a difference if you would use `==` (only for the first run though, until [the secondary keys will kick in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31989067/fastest-method-to-replace-data-values-conditionally-in-data-table-speed-compari/).)

Comment: Also, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16666183/find-values-in-a-given-interval-without-a-vector-scan?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) for possible solutions

Answer (score 1):

OK, here are some proper benchmarks. The time units in your two benchmarks are probably not the same.

```
library(rbenchmark)
library(data.table)

set.seed(42)
#using sample to rule out ALTREP influence
df <- data.table(id = sample(1e7, replace = TRUE), val = runif(1e7, 0, 1))
df_sort <- copy(df)
setkey(df_sort, val)

benchmark('raw' = { l = length(unique(df$id[df$val >=0.1]))}, 
          'sort' = {l = length(unique(df_sort$id[df_sort$val >=0.1]))},
          'raw_DT' = {df[val >=0.1, uniqueN(id)]},
          'sort_DT' = {df_sort[val >=0.1, uniqueN(id)]},
          'raw_DT_length' = {df[val >=0.1, length(unique(id))]},
          replications=20, order = "relative")
#           test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
#3        raw_DT           20   9.422    1.000     8.742    0.680          0         0
#4       sort_DT           20   9.617    1.021     8.901    0.697          0         0
#2          sort           20  15.237    1.617    14.016    1.222          0         0
#1           raw           20  15.313    1.625    14.128    1.190          0         0
#5 raw_DT_length           20  16.719    1.774    15.473    1.233          0         0


benchmark(unique_length = length(unique(df$id)), 
          uniqueN = uniqueN(df$id),
          replications=20, order = "relative")
#           test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
#2       uniqueN           20   7.708    1.000     7.340    0.368          0         0
#1 unique_length           20  15.683    2.035    14.765    0.920          0         0

benchmark(subset_base = df$id[df$val >=0.1], 
          subset_data.table = df[val >=0.1, id],
          subset_data.table_keyed = df_sort[val >=0.1, id],
          replications=20, order = "relative")
#                     test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
#1             subset_base           20   1.546    1.000     1.206    0.340          0         0
#3 subset_data.table_keyed           20   2.360    1.527     2.046    0.314          0         0
#2       subset_data.table           20   2.493    1.613     2.184    0.309          0         0
```

Some remarks: Your base R approach does not use data.table capabilities at all. Base R logical operators don't make use of sorting; they are a simple vector scan. `uniqueN` beats `length(unique())` as it should. `data.table` subsetting is not optimized for `>=` (yet). If you really want to improve the timings you should write a `uniqueNSubset` function with Rcpp that makes use of the data being sorted (I would also sort the IDs).

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.4

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8/C/de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.11.2 rbenchmark_1.0.0 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.5.0 tools_3.5.0
```

Comment: `uniqueN` was improved only in the recent version actually, up until not long ago it was [slow](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1120). Re optimization over `>=` once it would be implemented, it still won't matter (after the first run) because of secondary keys. Also, [there have been (successful) attempts to overcome scanning the whole vector without Rcpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16666183/find-values-in-a-given-interval-without-a-vector-scan?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

Comment: Reference re future optimization for >= https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1068